# enabling a django download button for pdf download

Tags: python, html, django, django-views

I am trying to set up a django button so I can download a file. I tried following along a tutorial but I think i'm missing something. The `urls.py` code below is the `urls.py` file that i generated in the app section of my project. I am not sure if that is the correct one to be using. 
The code below is not working, local host doesn't load the page. however when i comment out `url('download_my_pdf', download_pdf),` in my `urls.py` the site loads as we dont have that link back to the code in the views.

INDEX.HTML:

```
<input type="button" value="Download" onclick="window.open('download_my_pdf')">
```

VIEWS.PY:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from wsgiref.util import FileWrapper

def index(request):
return render(request, "index.html", {})

def home(request):
return render(request, "home.html", {})

def download_pdf(request):
filename = 'faults.pdf'
content = FileWrapper(filename)
response = HttpResponse(content, content_type='application/pdf')
response['Content-Length'] = os.path.getsize(filename)
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s' % 'faults.pdf'
return response
```

URLS.PY

```
from django.urls import url
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
 path('', views.index, name="index"),
 path('home', views.home, name="home"),
 url('download_my_pdf', download_pdf),
]
```

[image]

Comment: update `url('download_my_pdf', download_pdf),` ______________ to ______________ `path('download_my_pdf', views.download_pdf),`

Comment: When great the site loads, however when i click the download button now it throw 'str' object has no attribute 'read' error. so no file is actually downloaded. It hi lights line 16 in my views.py: response = HttpResponse(content, content_type='application/pdf')

Answer (score 2):

views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse, Http404

def open_file(request, *args, **kwargs):
    path = str(kwargs['p'])

    file_path = 'your path'
    if os.path.exists(file_path):
        with open(file_path, 'rb') as fh:
            response = HttpResponse(fh.read(), content_type="application/vnd.ms-excel")
            response['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline; filename=' + os.path.basename(file_path)
            return response
    raise Http404
```

templates/template.html

```html
                            <a class="button" href="{% url 'open-file' path %}">Download</a>
```

urls.py

```
path('open/<str:path>/', views.open_file, name='open-file'),
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please try to be as clear and complete in your answer as possible. Try adding some explanation besides adding code.

Answer (score 0):

for your code, try to "views.download_pdf" in your urls file, you 're using it without importing it

Comment: When great the site loads, however when i click the download button now it throw `'str' object has no attribute 'read'` error. so no file is actually downloaded. It hi lights line 16 in my views.py: `response = HttpResponse(content, content_type='application/pdf')`

Answer (score 0):

As others have already suggested, your urls.py has an error. You're missing the views.download_pdf part. I would also suggest naming it so it can be used in the future for a possible reverse function. Also, for consistency and simplicity, it is best to stick to the path function. The URL function is an alias of the re_path function that allows regex functionality, but this is not needed for your problem.

[Django url reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/urls/)

```py
from django.urls import url
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
 path('', views.index, name="index"),
 path('home', views.home, name="home"),
 path('download_my_pdf', views.download_pdf, name="download_pdf"),
]
```

With the URL routing set, one can create a download button. I prefer the below button. It looks like a button because it holds the bootstrap class, but underneath it is a simple link to your download_pdf view.

```html
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="{% url 'download_pdf' %}" role="button">Download pdf</a>
```

After pushing the button link you get redirected to your download_pdf view. This should activate the download. I did not test your view code. If it still does not work, let me know. There might be another option involving [PdfFileReader](https://pythonhosted.org/PyPDF2/PdfFileReader.html). [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/Questions/1180115/add-text-to-existing-pdf-using-python)

It might be possible to read your file with PdfFileReader and then return it in your download_pdf view. Good luck!